# Relaxation of copy initialization requirements in C++17

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, c++17, copy-initialization

I'm confused by the [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) statements:

> [...] The result of the conversion, which is a **prvalue expression (since
>   C++17)** if a converting constructor was used, is then used to
>   direct-initialize the object.
>   **The last step is usually optimized out and the result of the
>   conversion is constructed directly in the memory allocated for the
>   target object, but the appropriate constructor (move or copy) is
>   required to be accessible even though it's not used. (until C++17)**

I tested the code `std::atomic_int atom = 1;` on gcc 8.0.1, and it compiles with C++17 but [fails](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zM4ND91yMD1B3cQa) with C++14 with the following error:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::atomic<int>::atomic(const std::atomic<int>&)'
   std::atomic_int atom = 1;
                          ^
```

Does that mean the appropriate constructor (move or copy) is (always?) no longer required to be accessible in C++17?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where [copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is *mandatory* in C++17, these constructors are never used. In that case there is nothing to check.

In earlier versions, where elision was merely optional, the access checks were required to get consistent result between compilers. Still happens in C++17 for the cases where the elision is not mandatory.

Comment: Then to write portable code, one should not assume that constructor accessibility is not checked, right?

Comment: @Lingxi: If you want to be portable with C++14, you have to follow C++14's rules.

Comment: @NicolBolas Let's say I want to be portable with C++17. Still, whether accessibility check is performed depends on whether copy elision is mandatory, which is not specified by the standard.

Comment: @Lingxi: "*Let's say I want to be portable with C++17.*" What does that mean? You're either writing code that compiles in C++14 (which C++17 is backwards compatible with) or code that compiles in C++17 (which C++14 is not necessarily forwards compatible with).

Comment: @Lingxi - Of course the cases where copy elision is mandatory *are* specified in the C++17 standard. I didn't quote anything because I have never ever tried to return an object with a private move constructor, so also haven't bothered to find out *exactly* when it would now work (or not).